# Загрузка значений из файла xml

Tags: c#, xml

Имею такой xml файл

```
<root>
    <mainsettings>
        <version>v.0.1.0</version>
        <Window>
            <H>100</H>
            <L>200</L>
        </Window>
    </mainsettings>
.....
</root>
```

Как правильно загрузить значения в переменные?
В данный момент делаю это вот так

```
var settings = xDoc.Descendants("MainSettings");
Win.Height = Convert.ToInt32(settings .Descendants("Window").Descendants("Width").First().Value);
Win.Length = Convert.ToInt32(settings .Descendants("Window").Descendants("Length").First().Value);
```

Может есть какой-то правильный способ?

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам нужно именно _загрузить значения в переменные_, а не _десериализовать структуру данных_?

Comment: Знать бы еще что это) Думаю мне все таки нужно загрузить в переменные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно просто считать значения без получения объектной структуры всего файла, возможно, подойдёт простое

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
var win = doc.Root.Element("mainsettings").Element("Window");
var h = (int)win.Element("H");
var w = (int)win.Element("L");
```

Comment: Как мне представляется, это мало отличается от изначального варианта, который использует автор вопроса

Comment: @AndreiS.: С моей точки зрения, намного компактнее. Тем более, код ТС падает, а мой нет. Плюс использование `Descendants` в данном контексте сомнительно.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете воспользоваться объектом [XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/tz8csy73(v=vs.110).aspx) для десериализации xml

Вот код для вашего случая

```
class Window {public int H; public int L;}
class MainSettings {public string version; public Window Window; }
class Root {public MainSettings mainsettings;}

MainSettings DeserializeSetting(string fullFilename)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root), new XmlRootAttribute("root"));
    using (var fs = new FileStream(fullFilename, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var reader = XmlReader.Create(fs);
        var root = (Root)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        return root.mainsettings;
    }
}
```

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, для XML-сериализации нужны свойства, а не поля.

Comment: @VladD Вы ошибаетесь. Здесь https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/tz8csy73(v=vs.110).aspx используются поля. Я думаю XmlSerializer достаточно умный, чтобы проверить как открытые поля, так и свойства. P/s Слово "примерный" в тексте ответа означает, что код написан умозрительно без проверки работоспособности

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще вот такой способ:

```
public class Window
{
 public int H {get;set;}
 public int W {get;set;}
}

List<Window> wins = new List<Window>();
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(filepath);
XmlNodeList elemList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Window");
foreach (XmlNode node in elemList)
{
    wins.Add(new Window
             {
                 W = Convert.ToInt32(node.SelectSingleNode("L").InnerText),
                 H = Convert.ToInt32(node.SelectSingleNode("H").InnerText)
             });
}
```